# Ancetode behind the incarnation of Nara and Narayana vis a vis Arjuna and Krishna

Tags: krishna, avatars, vishnu

Adiseshu wipes out all others except Nara and Narayana who become as incarnations of Arjuna and Krishna. As the story unfolds only Krishna and Arjuna match wave lengths. Can any one  give more clarity to this topic on which I have a vague Idea. I am very keen to know it from anybody

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Could you clarify what exactly are you asking?  Are you trying to find a story about Adiseshan sparing Nara and Narayana during the destruction of the world?